# django object ids increment between unit tests

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-testing

I'm using Django 1.2.3-3+squeeze1 on Debian squeeze with PostgreSQL 8.4.7-0squeeze2 (though I don't think PostgreSQL is relevant here), and running Django unit tests based on unittest with the following setUp and tearDown

```
   def setUp(self):
        print "running setup"
        self.c = Client()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('faheem', 'faheem@email.unc.edu', 'foo')
        self.logged_in = self.c.login(username='faheem', password='foo')
        settings.MEDIA_ROOT='/tmp/'
        #settings.ZIP_UPLOAD='/var/tmp/zip/'

    def tearDown(self):
        print "running teardown"
        FolderUpload.objects.all().delete()
        FileUpload.objects.all().delete()
        ZipFileUpload.objects.all().delete()
        OldFileUpload.objects.all().delete()
        # FIXME: Quick & dirty fix for the time being. Should make this a delete method.
        os.system("rm -rf "+ settings.ZIP_UPLOAD + "/*")
```

The idea is for everything to be removed from the database between running unit tests. According to the unittest documentation,
that is what `tearDown` is for. The problem I am having is that there still seems to be some state saved between the different unit tests.
Specifically, I'm seeing that the ids get incremented. So lets say if I create one `ZipFileUpload` object in `test1`, and then create one `ZipFileUpload` object in `test2`, then I would expect both ids to be `1`, but what I see is that is id `1` for `test1` and id `2` for`test2`. This would make sense if the ids come from some index which lives outside these tables. I don't know enough about how Diango does this to know if that is in fact the case. If they are doing it this way, I have no idea why. Any clarification on this point would be appreciated.

Regardless, I would settle for a clean way to drop the database, if anyone can suggest one. This method should probably go into `teadDown`. [Testing Django applications](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/testing/) mentions the following function, but I failed to import it from `django.test.utils`. Confusingly, this function seems to be in `django/db/backends/creation.py`.

> destroy_test_db(old_database_name, verbosity=1)
>
> Destroys the database whose name is in stored in NAME in the DATABASES, and sets NAME to use the provided name.

The first part of this sentence is Ok  - "Destroy the database whose name is stored in NAME in the DATABASES",
but what is meant by "sets NAME to use the provided name" mean? I assume the provided name is `old_database_name`,

It is not clear what `NAME` is in the context. Is it the `NAME` in `DATABASES`, and if so,
why do I need to set something that is already set? 
I assume the provided name is `old_database_name`,
 but if so, why would I want to set it to an argument called `old_database_name`?
This sentence is unchanged in development docs.

EDIT:

After a reply from Steve Mayne (see below), I thought I would elaborate on the background of this a little bit.

This application was originally written over 2007/2008/2009, including the unit tests. During most of that time, I was using pre 1.0 releases of Django. According to [Ken Cochran's Django Release History](http://kencochrane.net/blog/2010/05/Django-Project-Release-History/), 1.0 was released on September 3rd, 2008. The setup described worked fine during that time. I see that the tearDown function above was originally written in December 2007. So, perhaps Django's behavior changed?

In hindsight, I realise that emptying the tables, as `tearDown` does above, does not guarantee that the id count will be reset to `1`, since the sequence can be a separate object from the table.

Thanks to Steve for his solution. If it exists, I'd like to hear about a portable solution to the sequence reset. I'd also be interested in an explanation of how to make the `destroy_test_db` function above work.

Comment: Why do you need the integer IDs to be the same?  The IDs are incremented by the database, not by Django per-se.

Comment: @Steve: It's not critical, but it the tables are dropped after every test, shouldn't the ids increment from one again? In my testing, it is used to keep track of which objects are being saved and when.

Comment: Yes, if you drop the database you'll start again.  You can also reset the table sequence.  It's dangerous to rely on IDs to give you information in testing though.  Your app's behaviour should be ID agnostic.

Comment: @SteveMayne You're right, except when you're testing something that uses ID to perform, like a REST API.

Answer (score 5):

You can reset the ID sequence on each table using the following SQL:

```
SELECT pg_catalog.setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('table_name', 'id'), 1);
```

You should only do this if your table is empty.

Comment: Thank your for your helpful answer and comments. My tests do not rely on id checking, not does my application. I'm just doing it for sanity checking, and it seems like a harmless thing to do in this context. I guess resetting the table sequence is an alternative to dropping the database, and certainly faster. Should I use the approach described in [Executing custom SQL directly](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly) to do this?